# Refactoring Case Classes With Common Attributes and Functions

Tags: scala

A few of case classes share a few common attributes and one functions using those common attributes. I would like to refactor them so that

1. the copy function can be used and one or more those attributes can
   be altered with the function
2. those common functions only need to be defined once

I have tried to create a trait on the top of those case classes. This approach solves the second problem, but not the first one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See this: https://gist.github.com/odersky/56323c309a186cffe9af you probably will have to implement your own copy method in each subclass and use f-bounded polymorphism or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get to what you want, without using reflection, is, probably, something like this:

```
 trait Foo[T <: Foo[_]] {
   def foo: String
   def copyMe(foo: String): T
 }

 case class Bar(foo: String, bar: String) extends Foo[Bar] {
    def copyMe(foo: String) = copy(foo=foo)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. Just wondering why you have a type for the trait? Any advantages? I have a function which takes its case class data types as parameters. A typed trait doesn't work in the situation. Also, the copyMe function needs a returned data type.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the return type annotation (fixed now). Incidentally, this is why the T type is needed: you want `copyMe` return the same type that's being copied, not the trait type.

Comment: I see. That makes a sense. But, how to special the generic type in function parameter? Without the parameterized trait, I can define a function as a parameter of another function as f: Foo => Option[Foo], or myFunc(f:  Foo => Option[Foo]). What is shall be with a parameterized trait instead?

Comment: You can parametrize `myFunc` as well: `def myFunc[T <: Foo[T]](f: T => Option[T])`

Comment: Thanks again. I already look into this option. Those functions I need to pass into the function are from different classes. If I have to have a parameterized function as a parameter, I need to create a new function which invoke different classes'  functions based on the input parameter data type, I guess. That would create more work/code. The whole purpose I try to do here is to reduce the code or a duplicated coding pattern.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are talking about here: the type parameter is there exactly as a way to make it work with "different classes".

Comment: Sorry, I should say that I need to create new functions which wrap a corresponding function with a given data type.